# Is it possible to run a program to redirect all port 5938 access to port 59000?

Tags: windows-7, windows, port, port-redirection

We'd like some sort of program that redirects all reads/writes to port 5938, to port 59000. It has to work in both directions, kind of like a "port tunnel".

Is this possible?

Comment: Generally you would just configure the program to listen on the desired port, so in this case listen on port 59000 instead of port 5938.

Comment: The built-in port proxy might do what you need.  Start netsh and go to the interface portproxy context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [TcpTrace](http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcpTrace/).  (Download link [here](http://www.pocketsoap.com/tcptrace/tcpTrace081.zip).)  It's a free Windows tool that lets you intercept and forward a TCP port for diagnostic purposes.  Note that this is a GUI tool, not a command-line tool or background service.

I've used TcpTrace before for debugging custom socket-based application protocols.  Assuming the connections you want to proxy are simple enough – i.e. the application protocol doesn't encode any new server/port information in the payload (such as an HTTP redirect) – then TcpTrace should accomplish what you are asking, i.e. passing the traffic through from one TCP port to another.